# Why 4 divs with `width: 25vw;` cannot align together?

Tags: html, css, alignment, viewport-units

There are 4 divs, each of them has `width: 25vw;` and `height: 100vh;`. I thought they could **horizontally align in a line** and so that tile the whole browser viewport. But they didn't. A line break was between the 3rd and the 4th div, and the scroll bar also appeared.

Then I inspected them, and DevTools told me the computed width of each was 480px, which exactly equaled to 25vw(My screen is 1920 * 1080).

Finally, I gave the `body` `overflow: hidden`. The scroll bar disappeared, and the viewport was filled with 4 divs. Everything was fine, except I got totally confused. Why? 100vw & 100vh shouldn't make any overflow.

Here is my code:

```css
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 0;
}

div {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 25vw;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: lightblue;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div>
  <div>4</div>
</body>
```

or

```css
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

div {
  float: left;
  width: 25vw;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: lightblue;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div>
  <div>4</div>
</body>
```

P.S. I have tried both `display: inline-block;` and `float: left;` on Chrome & Firefox & Chromium Edge, the results are the same.

P.P.S. After saw the comments & answers, I tried to give the `body` `width: 100vw;`, and everything got nice. It seems that it is 25vw > the width of the `body` that causes the overflow. But still, I cannot understand this behavior. As far as I am concerned, the body is a block, and its width will be extended until equal to its content width if there is enough space. Since 100vw doesn't exceed the viewport, there is no overflow. The only reasonable explanation here is that the `body` has its own width by default, which value is less than 100vw, so the line break and scroll bar appears. The question is, is it true? Where is the default value from? I inspected it and found the value is 1519.2px. Why so strange?

New code:

```css
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  width: 100vw;
}

div {
  float: left;
  width: 25vw;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: lightblue;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div>
  <div>4</div>
</body>
```

Comment: the float should work fine

Comment: Really, not "how to remove spaces between inline-block elements". Question already has body font-size = 0, and in Firefox even using float doesn't fix the issue. It would be nice to understand what browsers are doing here.

Comment: 1. Make sure, that you dont have any margin, padding, borders.
2. Make sure the parent has 100% width and no margin, padding, border
3. It would be much easier to use display:flex for this case

Comment: Are scrollbars visible on your page?

Comment: @Alohci both snippets look fine for me in Firefox and Chrome so maybe it's just a bug?

Comment: I still think "Finally, I gave the body overflow: hidden. The scroll bar disappeared, and the viewport was filled with 4 divs" is the key to this question. @TemaniAfif the new snippets work in a vacuum, but if the OP had any other content on the page and system settings that "show scroll bars always", then the scrollbars will break this layout. Maybe OP will return :)

Comment: @Alohci Yes, you are right. I used `font-size: 0;` to avoid the whitespace. Maybe I just don't understand the browser's behavior.

Comment: @WolfgangBlessen Code posted above is all I wrote except the outermost `html` tags. I have already removed `body`'s `padding` & `margin`. In the case of `display: inline-block`, elements are in a line, and the width of their "containing box" is `auto` to extend as long as possible, namely as long as the whole viewport.  In the case of `float: left`, things are similar. The point here is not just to make it work(just using an `overflow: hidden`), but I want to know what exactly happened, and why 4 * 25vw will cause the unexpected overflow.

Comment: @sallf Yes, 4 * 25vw divs make an overflow and a line break, the scrollbar is visible. And if I add the `overflow: hidden`, the scrollbar disappears and divs align. By the way, what is 'OP'?

Comment: @TemaniAfif Firefox, Chrome & Chromium Edge behave the same. I don't think it is a bug that different browser vendors make the same mistakes.

Comment: @Kento on my side all behave correctly so it can be a bug since we don't have the same output

Answer (score 0):

For horizontal aligning it's best you use flexbox.

```
body{
 display: flex;
 width: 100vw;
}
body div{
 flex: 0 0 25%;
 max-width: 25%;
}
```

And be sure all margin, padding and border space are removed from the body

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It works. But I want to know why 4 * 25vw causes an overflow. In my code, there are no extra padding/border/margin things.

Answer (score -1):

The reason is because `vw` doesn't take into account the scrollbar. So if you have a div at `width: 100vw` and there is a visible scrollbar, that div will overflow the screen slightly.

> The viewport-percentage lengths are relative to the size of the
> initial containing block. When the height or width of the initial
> containing block is changed, they are scaled accordingly. However, any
> scrollbars are assumed not to exist.

[csswg](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-values-3/#viewport-relative-lengths)

You might have better luck setting the div to `width: 25%` which would factor in the scrollbars.

Comment: I don't understand yet. Certainly if there is a scroll bar, the width of it should be taken into account . In my opinion, the scroll bar will appear only if there is an overflow. 4 * 25vw equals to 100vw and should cause no overflow.  But scroll bar is still there.  So I confused.